# What are uses of polymorphic kinds?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, higher-kinded-types

Polymorphic kinds are an extension to Haskell's type system, [supported](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/bin/view/Ehc/UhcUserDocumentation#3_5_Kind_inference_and_signature) by UHC, allowing

```
data A x y = A (y x)
```

to be typed (kinded?) as `a -> (a -> *) -> *`. What are they useful for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible usage example can be using conal's [TypeCompose](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose) for composing monad transformers in point-free style.

```
type MyT = StateT Foo :. MaybeT :. ContT Bar
```

(just as an example, I have no idea what one's going to do with those foos and bars..)

Instead of:

```
type MyT m = StateT Foo (MaybeT (ContT Bar m))
```

(this would have the same result apart from `newtype`-wrappers)

Currently you'll need to duplicate the combinators code for different kinds, and this extension abolishes the repetition and allows using one piece of code to rule them all.

Answer (score 11):

[**Adding Polymorphic Kinds to GHC**](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PolymorphicKinds)

The background to this question would be the [motivation in general for a more expressive kind system](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/KindSystem#Motivation).

That is, the overall reason to add polymorphic kinds to Haskell is to improve the experience of *type level programming*. Currently type level programming in Haskell proceeds in a essentially untyped "[kind](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/KindSystem)" level. A richer kind language will make type level programming in Haskell, in general, easier.

A more concrete example would be to remove the (dynamic) Typeable constraint from generics of the SYB style ([citation](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PolymorphicKinds#Example:Typeable123..)), as well as improving overall support for higher-kinded generic programming..

Answer (score 1):

They are useful for defining functions that operate over data constructors with arbitrary arity, of course!

A concrete example could be a function that, given a data constructor with arbitrary arity, returns a new data constructor that wraps the given constructor in Some().