# Functions don't just have types: They ARE Types. And Kinds. And Sorts. Help put a blown mind back together

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, type-systems, higher-kinded-types

I was doing my usual "Read a chapter of [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) before bed" routine, feeling like my brain was expanding with every code sample. At this point I was convinced that I understood the core awesomeness of Haskell, and now just had to understand the standard libraries and type classes so that I could start writing real software.

So I was reading the chapter about applicative functors when all of a sudden the book claimed that functions don't merely have types, they *are* types, and can be treated as such (For example, by making them instances of type classes). (->) is a type constructor like any other.

My mind was blown yet again, and I immediately jumped out of bed, booted up the computer, went to GHCi and discovered the following:

```
Prelude> :k (->)
(->) :: ?? -> ? -> *
```

- What on earth does it mean?
- If (->) is a type constructor, what are the value constructors? I can take a guess, but would have no idea how define it in traditional `data (->) ... = ... | ... | ...` format. It's easy enough to do this with any other type constructor: `data Either a b = Left a | Right b`. I suspect my inability to express it in this form is related to the extremly weird type signature.
- What have I just stumbled upon? Higher kinded types have kind signatures like `* -> * -> *`. Come to think of it... (->) appears in kind signatures too! Does this mean that not only is it a type constructor, but also a kind constructor? Is this related to the question marks in the type signature?

I have read somewhere (wish I could find it again, Google fails me) about being able to extend type systems arbitrarily by going from Values, to Types of Values, to Kinds of Types, to Sorts of Kinds, to something else of Sorts, to something else of something elses, and so on forever. Is this reflected in the kind signature for (->)? Because I've also run into the notion of the Lambda cube and the calculus of constructions without taking the time to really investigate them, and if I remember correctly it is possible to define functions that take types and return types, take values and return values, take types and return values, and take values which return types.

If I had to take a guess at the type signature for a function which takes a value and returns a type, I would probably express it like this:

```
a -> ?
```

or possibly

```
a -> *
```

Although I see no fundamental immutable reason why the second example couldn't easily be interpreted as a function from a value of type a to a value of type *, where * is just a type synonym for string or something.

The first example better expresses a function whose type transcends a type signature in my mind: "a function which takes a value of type a and returns something which cannot be expressed as a type."

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You touch so many interesting points in your question, so I am
afraid this is going to be a long answer :)

### Kind of (->)

The kind of `(->)` is `* -> * -> *`, if we disregard the boxity GHC
inserts. But there is no circularity going on, the `->`s in the
kind of `(->)` are kind arrows, not function arrows. Indeed, to
distinguish them kind arrows could be written as `(=>)`, and then
the kind of `(->)` is `* => * => *`.

We can regard `(->)` as a type constructor, or maybe rather a type
operator.  Similarly, `(=>)` could be seen as a *kind operator*, and
as you suggest in your question we need to go one 'level' up. We
return to this later in the section **Beyond Kinds**, but first:

### How the situation looks in a dependently typed language

You ask how the type signature would look for a function that takes a
value and returns a type. This is impossible to do in Haskell:
functions cannot return types!  You can simulate this behaviour using
type classes and type families, but let us for illustration change
language to the dependently typed language
[Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php). This is a
language with similar syntax as Haskell where juggling types together
with values is second nature.

To have something to work with, we define a data type of natural
numbers, for convenience in unary representation as in
[Peano Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms).
Data types are written in
[GADT](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GADT) style:

```
data Nat : Set where
    Zero : Nat
    Succ : Nat -> Nat
```

Set is equivalent to * in Haskell, the "type" of all (small) types,
such as Natural numbers. This tells us that the type of `Nat` is
`Set`, whereas in Haskell, Nat would not have a type, it would have
a kind, namely `*`. In Agda there are no kinds, but everything has
a type.

We can now write a function that takes a value and returns a type.
Below is a the function which takes a natural number `n` and a type,
and makes iterates the `List` constructor `n` applied to this
type. (In Agda, `[a]` is usually written `List a`)

```
listOfLists : Nat -> Set -> Set
listOfLists Zero     a = a
listOfLists (Succ n) a = List (listOfLists n a)
```

Some examples:

```
listOfLists Zero               Bool = Bool
listOfLists (Succ Zero)        Bool = List Bool
listOfLists (Succ (Succ Zero)) Bool = List (List Bool)
```

We can now make a `map` function that operates on `listsOfLists`.
We need to take a natural number that is the number of iterations
of the list constructor. The base cases are when the number is
`Zero`, then `listOfList` is just the identity and we apply the function.
The other is the empty list, and the empty list is returned.
The step case is a bit move involving: we apply `mapN` to the head
of the list, but this has one layer less of nesting, and `mapN`
to the rest of the list.

```
mapN : {a b : Set} -> (a -> b) -> (n : Nat) ->
       listOfLists n a -> listOfLists n b
mapN f Zero     x         = f x
mapN f (Succ n) []        = []
mapN f (Succ n) (x :: xs) = mapN f n x :: mapN f (Succ n) xs
```

In the type of `mapN`, the `Nat` argument is named `n`, so the rest of
the type can depend on it. So this is an example of a type that
depends on a value.

<sub>As a side note, there are also two other named variables here,
namely the first arguments, `a` and `b`, of type `Set`. Type
variables are implicitly universally quantified in Haskell, but
here we need to spell them out, and specify their type, namely
`Set`. The brackets are there to make them invisible in the
definition, as they are always inferable from the other arguments.</sub>

### Set is abstract

You ask what the constructors of `(->)` are. One thing to point out
is that `Set` (as well as `*` in Haskell) is abstract: you cannot
pattern match on it. So this is illegal Agda:

```
cheating : Set -> Bool
cheating Nat = True
cheating _   = False
```

Again, you can simulate pattern matching on types constructors in
Haskell using type families, one canoical example is given on
[Brent Yorgey's blog](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/typed-type-level-programming-in-haskell-part-ii-type-families/).
Can we define `->` in the Agda? Since we can return types from
functions, we can define an own version of `->` as follows:

```
_=>_ : Set -> Set -> Set
a => b = a -> b
```

(infix operators are written `_=>_` rather than `(=>)`) This
definition has very little content, and is very similar to doing a
type synonym in Haskell:

```
type Fun a b = a -> b
```

### Beyond kinds: Turtles all the way down

As promised above, everything in Agda has a type, but then
the *type* of `_=>_`  must have a type! This touches your point
about sorts, which is, so to speak, one layer above Set (the kinds).
In Agda this is called `Set1`:

```
FunType : Set1
FunType = Set -> Set -> Set
```

And in fact, there is a whole hierarchy of them! Set is the type of
"small" types: data types in haskell.  But then we have `Set1`,
`Set2`, `Set3`, and so on. `Set1` is the type of types which mentions
`Set`. This hierarchy is to avoid inconsistencies such as Girard's
paradox.

As noticed in your question, `->` is used for types and kinds in
Haskell, and the same notation is used for function space at all
levels in Agda. This must be regarded as a built in type operator,
and the constructors are lambda abstraction (or function
definitions).  This hierarchy of types is similar to the setting in
[System F omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F), and more
information can be found in the later chapters of
[Pierce's Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/).

### Pure type systems

In Agda, types can depend on values, and functions can return types,
as illustrated above, and we also had an hierarchy of
types. Systematic investigation of different systems of the lambda
calculi is investigated in more detail in Pure Type Systems. A good
reference is
[Lambda Calculi with Types](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/~zhaohui/Barendregt92.pdf) by Barendregt,
where PTS are introduced on page 96, and many examples on page 99 and onwards.
You can also read more about the lambda cube there.

Comment: Brilliant answer with lots of juicy info. Right as I'm thinking I've stumbled upon the most amazing abstract language ever along comes a new one. :P Time to learn Agda, coq, omega, etc. It'd also be sweet if the language extension described in this series of blog posts was implemented http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/typed-type-level-programming-in-haskell-part-i-functional-dependencies/ essentially saying "screw paradoxes, we want convenience" and collapsing the value,type,kind,sort,... heirarchy into a single level (somewhat, there's more to it than that)

Comment: In the upcoming 7.4 version of GHC we can look forward to not only [Polymorphic Kinds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061428/what-are-uses-of-polymorphic-kinds) but also [Kind Promotion](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/stable/docs/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism-and-promotion.html) which makes data types available on the kind level. Both are described in the article [Giving Haskell a Promotion](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/dimitris/fc-kind-poly.pdf). If you can't wait: [GHC 7.4 RC2](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2012-January/021714.html). Cheers!

Answer (score 18):

Firstly, the `?? -> ? -> *` kind is a GHC-specific extension. The `?` and `??` are just there to deal with unboxed types, which behave differently from just `*` (which has to be boxed, as far as I know). So `??` can be any normal type or an unboxed type (e.g. `Int#`); `?` can be either of those or  an unboxed tuple. There is more information here: [Haskell Weird Kinds: Kind of (->) is ?? -> ? -> *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034264/haskell-weird-kinds-kind-of-is)

I think a function can't return an unboxed type because functions are lazy. Since a lazy value is either a value or a thunk, it has to be boxed. Boxed just means it is a pointer rather than just a value: it's like `Integer()` vs `int` in Java.

Since you are probably not going to be using unboxed types in LYAH-level code, you can imagine that the kind of `->` is just `* -> * -> *`.

Since the `?` and `??` are basically just more general version of `*`, they do not have anything to do with sorts or anything like that.

However, since `->` is just a type constructor, you can actually partially apply it; for example, `(->) e` is an instance of `Functor` and `Monad`. Figuring out how to write these instances is a good mind-stretching exercise.

As far as value constructors go, they would have to just be lambdas (`\ x ->`) or function declarations. Since functions are so fundamental to the language, they get their own syntax.

Comment: "As far as value constructors go, they would have to just be lambdas (\ x ->) or function declarations. Since functions are so fundamental to the language, they get their own syntax." Thats sweet. Is there any way to cut through the syntax sugar though? Is it actually possible to define the (->) from within haskell by using data declarations?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but I'm hardly an expert :)

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle: Functions are at the heart of Haskell. If you were to "define the (->) from within Haskell by using data declarations", what would you define it in terms of, if not (->) itself?

Comment: I can imagine doing it by saying something like data (->) a b = (=) fname a b | (=) (\\) a b. where fname is a compile time identifier (untypable), and \x->exp is just syntax sugar for (=) (\\) x exp. Would obviously require some sort of macro system to give meaning to fname. This data declaration would force you to use currying.